# Remove special characters in CSV header row and concatenate

Tags: java, mysql, csv, jdbc

I am trying to read a CSV file with headercolumns containing special characters and spaces. I need to push the CSV data to MySQL which throws syntax error when i create the table with predefined column names.

I am using Apache `commons.csv`. I tried to give my CSV format as follows:

```
CSVFormat format = CSVFormat.MYSQL.withSkipHeaderRecord().withHeader(headerstring).withDelimiter(',').withQuote('"');
```

headerstring is-

```
"auto_videoId", "videoId", "join_key", "eventId", "name", "LocationShelf", "Action", "Interaction", "TablesAvailability", "timeSpent"
```

Instead of taking it as individual column name entries, it is read as one string and throws error:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"auto_videoId", "videoId", "join_key", "eventId", "name", "LocationShelf", "Acti' at line 1
```

P.S- CSV already had the same column names but with special characters.

Comment: This question is not clear, Can you provide more information about this question with database code part where you getting this run time exception.

Comment: When you split the string by comma (,), your column names will still contain spaces at the end and MySql complains about that. You will have to get rid of the extra spaces.

Comment: Yes that can be an error but the string has not been split yet in the first place.(withDelimiter(',') ) is not working. and the string is read as a whole